# How to bind a grid or parsed XML data to a custom Windows Installer User Interface Dialog Box?

Tags: c#, installation, dialog, custom-controls, windows-installer

I'm creating a C# Windows Installer (using a C# Setup Project) for an application that I'm deploying and I have a problem with the limited UI controls.

Throughout the install process, I am logging all the installer activity to an XML file, so in the final screens of the install process, I'd like to parse that XML programmatically (perhaps through a custom action) and bind it to a grid onto the dialog box (which is pretty much like a Windows Form) or parse the XML and display it in text format.

The closest I've come is to attach the "Read Me" dialog box which takes an ".RTF" body of text to display, which I should have no problem parsing my XML into an .RTF format, however, how I can I programmatically do that through a custom action so that I can display it on the Read Me dialog box?

The other option is to create a brand new dialog box to bind a grid or parsed XML to. I've been looking at this article (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx[^]) using the Orca tool however, it's mainly for textbox control or radio buttons.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to use Wix?

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/

By the way what is problem displaying text in a dialog. Inside your custom action code you should be able to get a reference to your dialog box and display the xml into the dialog.